# automated popups and keyboard accessibility

Tags: accessibility

So, have a fun accessibility situation with an automatic ‘subscribe’ popup on a client’s site.   As per WCAG, everything more or less should be keyboard accessible, and the modal as is can’t be moved to through the keyboard.  Also as per WCAG, there isn’t suppose to be changes in context or focus unless manually triggered and with a warning, so can’t auto assign focus to the modal to have the user interact with it. And obviously can't leave it the way it is because it visually obstructs the content behind it.  Not quite sure what to do.

Based on my research so far, it seems the modal simply has to be made not automatic, and needs to be manually triggered by the user.

Any suggestions/feedback?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you are correct, automatic context switches are not good per WCAG. I believe you could get by with announcing the popup with appropriate contextual clues in the form of a screen reader alert or aria-label associated with the popup.

If the client wants to keep the popup automatic I would suggest adding focus to the popup so it can be navigated and closed by the user and also contextual alerts as I mentioned.

This website (leads to WCAG 3.2.2) https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html covers context switches and mentions alternatives to visual cues.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  One of the things that I noticed on the suggested page is "Changes of context are appropriate only when it is clear that such a change will happen in response to the user's action.".  There are numerous other references and examples on that page speaking of changes by the user, so based on that one URL, I still don't think that automatically moving focus to the automated popup without any user action is appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelR I agree. If it is possible to remove the automatic pop up it would be best to do so. I was just trying to give best workarounds in the event that the client did not want to remove the pop up itself.